# Exercise about using functions, pointers, and dynamic allocation (C)

Tags: c

Basically the exercise states as follows:

Write a program that has 3 functions:

1. Initialising the class grades.
2. Calculating the average, the highest, and the lowest grade.
3. Displaying all the grades, the average, the highest, and the lowest.

I want to better understand how to use dynamic allocation and function pointers to solve this problem. The number of students and their grades is not known and should be entered by the user.

Since I just want to know how to use dynamic allocation and function pointers, I only wrote a program using two functions: Initialising the grades and then displaying them. I will show you  the code I wrote. I know it is terrible and doesn't make much sense since I am kind of hazy in understanding heap and stack memories and how they work in relation with function pointers. Please help me understand how to correct this code. P.S : I don't want to use static memory allocation.

So here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

void init(int *n, float *a) {
    printf("How many students?\n");
    scanf("%d", n);
    int number = *n;
    a = (float *)calloc(*n, sizeof(float));
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        printf("student %d?\n", i + 1);
        scanf("%f", &a[i]);
    }
}

void display(int n, float a) {
    for (int i = 0; i <n; i++)
        printf("%.2f  ", a[i]); // I don't know how to display an array initialized dynamically.
}

int main() {
    int m;
    float b;
    init(&m, &b);
    display(m, b);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: regarding: `void display(int n,float a){`  the second parameter is a pointer to the array (doesn't matter if it is on the stack or on the heap)  so the signature should be: `void display(int n,float *a){`  -or- `void display(int n,float a[]){`  note: both these signatures are actually equivalent for our purposes, but the second one makes it clear that the second parameter is a pointer to an array

Comment: in function: `main()`, regarding: `float b;`   this will be the pointer to the allocated memory, so it should be: `float *b = NULL;`

Comment: OT: for robust code, when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  Any returned value other than the number of `input format conversion specifiers` is an indication that an error occurred.  suggest: `if( scanf( "%d", n ) != 1 ) { handle error and call exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: for robust code, regarding: `a=(float*)calloc(*n,sizeof(float));`  1) the returned type in c is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  casting just clutters the code. 2) that 'a' is the address of an address, so the statement should be: `*a = calloc( *n, sizeof(float) );`  3) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) use meaningful variable names.  Names like 'a' and 'b' are meaningless, even in the current context.  2) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: regarding: `void init(int * n,float *a){`  the second parameter is a pointer to a pointer so the signature should be: `void init( int *n, float **a ){`

Comment: regarding: `return 1;`  in general, a 0 returned value indicates success, and other values indicate some error occurred.

Comment: Your question is very hard to answer as you are asking multiple things (fix my code, how something works, a demonstration of how something works). It's probably better to ask a more focused question after you cleaned up some of the bugs in your code and have a better idea what to ask. This way, you will probably not get very useful answers out of SO.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation it isn't necessary to pass a pointer to float into `init`. With an integer, it can do it's job of allocating memory and returning a pointer to the allocated memory. Since a function can only return one value, a pointer to an integer is needed so `main` knows the number of floats allocated.
Consider using `fgets` to read a line. Then parse the line as needed. If the input is invalid, it has alread been removed from the input stream to allow for another try.  The do/while loops use `sscanf` to see if the input can be parsed and will try again if sscanf does not return 1 for success.
`main` can then pass the number of floats and a pointer to the floats to `display` to print each float.
`free` the allocated memory when it is no longer needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float *init (int *n) {//take a pointer to number of students and return pointer to float
    char line[100] = "";//for input
    int result = 0;//for return from sscanf
    do {
        printf ( "How many students?\n");
        if ( ! fgets ( line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
            perror ( "fgets problem");
            exit ( EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        result = sscanf ( line, "%d", n);
    } while ( 1 != result || *n <= 0);

    float *a = NULL;
    if ( NULL == ( a = calloc(*n, sizeof(float)))) {//was calloc successful
        fprintf ( stderr, "calloc problem\n");
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for ( int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
        do {
            printf ( "student %d?\n", i + 1);
            if ( ! fgets ( line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
                perror ( "fgets problem");
                exit ( EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            result = sscanf ( line, "%f", &a[i]);
        } while ( 1 != result);
    }
    return a;
}

void display ( int n, float *a){//takes number and pointer to floats
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%.2f  ", a[i]);//print each float
    }

int main ( void){
    int m = 0;
    float *b = NULL;
    b = init ( &m);
    display ( m, b);

    free ( b);//free the allocated memory

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: regarding: `fprintf ( stderr, "fgets problem\n");`  the function: `fgets()` sets `errno` to the code of the reason the function failed.  so a much better if() body would be: `{ perror( "fgets failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }` which will output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: regarding: `exit ( 0);`  in general, a exit value of 0 indicates success.  Suggest returning EXIT_FAILURE

Comment: Minor corner: Should `*n == 0`, `calloc(*n, sizeof(float))` is not certainly an out-of-memory.  Yet a good answer, UV.

Comment: @user3121023 `|| *n == 0` is a good useful addition.  `*n < 0` is problematic as `calloc(size_t, size_t)` takes unsigned arguments and negative `*n` is black hole of problems.